# How to overload parameters to pytest fixture?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

i seeking a solution to overload paramaters to the pytest_fixure function

```
@pytest.fixture()
def policies(cust_data):
  result={}
  if cust_data== 'Name':
    result[cust_data]='Umesh'
  elif cust_data == 'Id':
    result[cust_data]='123'
  return result



def test_policy():
  result = policies('Name')
  assert {'Name': 'Umesh'} == result, "Validation Passed"
```

#Expected:
The fixure function should return result based on the parameter that is being overloaded

```
{'Name': 'Umesh'}
or
{'Id': '123'} #if i pass id
```

#Actual:

This test return the error says

```
Fixture "policies" called directly. Fixtures are not meant to be called directly,
```

I want the fixure function to be dynamic.

Any solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a function from the fixture:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture()
def policies():
    def _policies(cust_data):
        result={}
        if cust_data== 'Name':
            result[cust_data]='Umesh'
        elif cust_data == 'Id':
            result[cust_data]='123'
        return result
    return _policies



def test_policy(policies):
    result = policies('Name')
    assert {'Name': 'Umesh'} == result, "Validation Passed"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try something below -

```
 @pytest.mark.parametrize("resource", [1, 2, 800], indirect=True)
 def test_resource(resource):
     assert resource.is_okay()

 @pytest.mark.parametrize("resource", [1, 5], indirect=True)
 def test_resource_other(resource):
     assert resource.is_okay()
```

Comment: Your approach of using indirect parametrisation is good but the way you demonstrate it is not (missing example of the fixture, irrelevant sample code instead of applying the solution to OP's code).